# Swift unit testing view model interface

Tags: swift, unit-testing, testing, mvvm

As I understand, it is best to only test public methods of a class.

Let's have a look at this example. I have a view model for the view controller.

```
protocol MyViewModelProtocol {

   var items: [SomeItem] { get }
   var onInsertItemsAtIndexPaths: (([IndexPath]) -> Void)? { get set }

   func viewLoaded()
}

class MyViewModel: MyViewModelProtocol {

   func viewLoaded() {
        let items = createDetailsCellModels()
        updateCellModels(with: items)
        requestDetails()
   }
}
```

I want to test class viewLoaded(). This class calls two other methods - updateItems() and requestDetails()
One of the methods sets up the items and the other one call API to retrieve data and update those items. Items array us updated two times and onInsertItemsAtIndexPaths are called two times - when setting up those items and when updating with new data.

I can test whether after calling viewLoaded() expected items are set up and that onInsertItemsAtIndexPaths is called.

However, the test method will become rather complex.

What is your view, should I test those two methods separately or just write this one huge test?

By testing only viewLoaded(), my idea is that the implementation can change and I only care that results are what I expect.

Answer (score 1):

I think the same thing, only public functions should be tested, since public ones use private ones, and your view on MVVM is correct. You can improve it by adding a DataSource and a Mapper that allows you to improve testing.

However, yes, the test seems huge to me, the tests should test simple units and ensure that small parts of the code work well, with the example you show is difficult, you need to divide by layers (clean code). 
In the example you load the data into the viewModel and make it difficult to mockup the data. But if you have a Domain layer you can pass the UseCase mock to the viewModel and control the result. If you run a test on your example, the result will also depend on what the endpoint returns. (404, 200, empty array, data with error ...). So it is important, for testing purposes, to have a good separation by layers. (Presentation, Domain and Data) to be able to test each one separately.

I give you an example of how I would test a view mode, sure there are better and cooler examples, but it's an approach.

Here you can see a viewModel

```
protocol BeersListViewModel: BeersListViewModelInput, BeersListViewModelOutput {}

protocol BeersListViewModelInput {
    func viewDidLoad()
    func updateView()
    func image(url: String?, index: Int) -> Cancellable?
}

protocol BeersListViewModelOutput {
    var items: Box<BeersListModel?> { get }
    var loadingStatus: Box<LoadingStatus?> { get }
    var error: Box<Error?> { get }
}

final class DefaultBeersListViewModel {
    private let beersListUseCase: BeersListUseCase
    private var beersLoadTask: Cancellable? { willSet { beersLoadTask?.cancel() }}
    var items: Box<BeersListModel?> = Box(nil)
    var loadingStatus: Box<LoadingStatus?> = Box(.stop)
    var error: Box<Error?> = Box(nil)

    @discardableResult
    init(beersListUseCase: BeersListUseCase) {
        self.beersListUseCase = beersListUseCase
    }

    func viewDidLoad() {
        updateView()
    }
}

// MARK: Update View
extension DefaultBeersListViewModel: BeersListViewModel {
    func updateView() {
        self.loadingStatus.value = .start
        beersLoadTask = beersListUseCase.execute(completion: { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let beers):
                let beers = beers.map { DefaultBeerModel(beer: $0) }
                self.items.value = DefaultBeersListModel(beers: beers)
            case .failure(let error):
                self.error.value = error
            }
            self.loadingStatus.value = .stop
        })
    }
}

// MARK: - Images
extension DefaultBeersListViewModel {
    func image(url: String?, index: Int) -> Cancellable? {
        guard let url = url else { return nil }
        return beersListUseCase.image(with: url, completion: { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let imageData):
                self.items.value?.items?[index].image.value = imageData
            case .failure(let error ):
              print("image error: \(error)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Here you can see the viewModel test using mocks for the data and view.

```
class BeerListViewModelTest: XCTestCase {
    private enum ErrorMock: Error {
        case error
    }

    class BeersListUseCaseMock: BeersListUseCase {

        var error: Error?
        var expt: XCTestExpectation?

        func execute(completion: @escaping (Result<[BeerEntity], Error>) -> Void) -> Cancellable? {
            let beersMock = BeersMock.makeBeerListEntityMock()
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error))
            } else {
                completion(.success(beersMock))
            }
            expt?.fulfill()
            return nil
        }

        func image(with imageUrl: String, completion: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) -> Cancellable? {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func testWhenAPIReturnAllData() {
        let beersListUseCaseMock = BeersListUseCaseMock()
        beersListUseCaseMock.expt = self.expectation(description: "All OK")
        beersListUseCaseMock.error = nil

        let viewModel = DefaultBeersListViewModel(beersListUseCase: beersListUseCaseMock)


        viewModel.items.bind { (_) in}
        viewModel.updateView()

        waitForExpectations(timeout: 10, handler: nil)
        XCTAssertNotNil(viewModel.items.value)
        XCTAssertNil(viewModel.error.value)
        XCTAssert(viewModel.loadingStatus.value == .stop)
    }

    func testWhenDataReturnsError() {
        let beersListUseCaseMock = BeersListUseCaseMock()
        beersListUseCaseMock.expt = self.expectation(description: "Error")
        beersListUseCaseMock.error = ErrorMock.error

        let viewModel = DefaultBeersListViewModel(beersListUseCase: beersListUseCaseMock)

        viewModel.updateView()

        waitForExpectations(timeout: 10, handler: nil)
        XCTAssertNil(viewModel.items.value)
        XCTAssertNotNil(viewModel.error.value)
        XCTAssert(viewModel.loadingStatus.value == .stop)
    }
}
```

in this way you can test the view, the business logic and the data separately, in addition to being a code that is very reusable.

Hope this helps you, I have it posted on github in case you need it.
https://github.com/cardona/MVVM